# ошибка HomeViewController [proj.HomeViewController initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift3

HomeViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit
var manager: HomeViewController = HomeViewController()

struct task {
    var name = "Name"
    var note = "Note"
}

class HomeViewController: NSObject {
    var tasks = [task]()

    func addTask(name: String, note: String){
    tasks.append(task(name: name, note: note))
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что метод не реализован в самом классе и NSObject не реализует его. Судя по всему HomeViewController должен наследоваться от UIViewController. Иначе зачем было импортить UIKit?